# cakephp !empty and isset difference?

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I am checking a variable using the following code to

```
if(!empty($var) && $var == 1)
{
       // do some thing
}
elseif(!empty($var) && $var == 0)
{
       // do some thing
}
```

But the elseif is not working 
If I  removed the !empty then its working fine.
what is the problem on that

Can any one explain these and also  differences between isset and !empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please peruse [the documentation](http://www.php.net/empty) on what PHP considers to be `empty`.

I'd rewrite your code as:

```
if (isset($var)) {
    if ($var == 1) {
        ...
    } else if ($var == 0) {
        ...
    } else {
        // if you're that specific you should handle any other case as well
    }
}
```